# Give relative path in qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How to give relative path in QTP to run any bat file.

For example :

user 1  location is `C:\Users\username\Documents\AppFolder\Application_xyz` and

user 2 location is `C:\AppFolder\Application_xyz`?

Comment: `AppFolder\Application_xyz` or `.\AppFolder\Application_xyz`, assuming that the working directory is set correctly.

Comment: you mean to say set with .\AppFolder\Application_xyz,?

Comment: I'm not familiar with QTP, so I don't know what that application uses as its working directory. But assuming that the working directory is `C:\Users\username\Documents` in the first case, and `C:\ ` in the second one, you can specify the relative path as I mentioned above. If that is not the case you need to provide more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have to execute .bat file that present in the folder called Application_xyz. Folder location would be different for different user .For Some user it might be in D drive. So  irrespective of folder structure it should pick .bat file and execute it. Can we get relative path of that folder using vb scripting?

Comment: Relative to *what*? How do you know or determine the path to which it is relative?

Comment: i want the path by giving the file name only

Comment: Then you need to search the entire filesystem for the file. Good luck.